# Mongoose find documents by child criteria

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm struggling trying to find all the docs with a specific property in the child. For example, I want to find all the users with their child active.

These are my models

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    child: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'child'
    }
});

const childSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    }
});
```

I tried with populate and match ( `.populate({path:'child', match: {active: true}})`) but I'm getting all the users with the property child as null if not active. I need only the users with an active child. All my researches head to use the dot syntax, but for any reason I get an empty array. See below:

```
let usersWithActiveChild = await User.find({'child.active': true}));
console.log(usersWithActiveChild) // --> displays '[]'
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished easily by using aggregation framework.

First we join two collections with [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).
Lookup result is array, but our relation with User and Child is one to one, so we get the first item by using `$arrayElemAt: ["$child", 0]`.

And lastly, we apply our filter `"child.active": true,` using [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZuH4mkZewgF)

```js
  let usersWithActiveChild = await User.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "childs",    //must be PHYSICAL collection name
        localField: "child",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "child",
      },
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        child: {
          $arrayElemAt: ["$child", 0],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "child.active": true,
      },
    },
  ]);
```

Sample docs:

```
db={
  "users": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a834e000102030405000000"),
      "child": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000")
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a834e000102030405000001"),
      "child": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001")
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a834e000102030405000002"),
      "child": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002")
    },

  ],
  "childs": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
      "active": true
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
      "active": false
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
      "active": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a834e000102030405000000"),
    "child": {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
      "active": true
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a834e000102030405000002"),
    "child": {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
      "active": true
    }
  }
]
```

Or as a better approach would be first getting activ childs, and then lookup with users like this:

```js
db.childs.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "active": true
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "child",
      as: "user"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nZ13WntWxeE)

Answer (score 1):

When you use a ref to refer to another schema, Mongoose stores the documents in separate collections in MongoDB.

The actual value stored in the `child` field of the user document is a `DBRef`.

If you were to look at the data directly in MongoDB you would find something similar to this:

User collection

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000")
  child: DBRef("child",ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),"DatabaseName")
}
```

Child collection:

```
{

  _id: ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
  active: true
}
```

When you populate the user object, Mongoose fetches the user document, and then fetches the child.  Since the user documents have been retrieved already, the `match` in the `populate` call filters the children, as you noted.

The dotted notation `'child.active'` can only be used if the child is stored in MongoDB as a subdocument, like

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000")
  child:{
    _id: ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    active: true
  }
}
```

But your child is defined as a ref, so this will not be the case.

In order to filter the list of user documents based on the content of the referenced child, you will need to either
- populate with match as you have done and then [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the result set, or
- [aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate) the user collection, [lookup](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate-lookup) the child documents, and then [match](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate-match) the child field.

Comment: The explanations about why my attempts are not working were so helpful!